# require() loaded after html is output

Tags: php, html, form-submit, require

In my code on index.php I require another script that performs a database query dependent on data i submitted in index.php. After pressing the submit button on index.php, index.php reloads and i expect the data being sent from index.php to be available in the required script. This is not always the case, sometimes the result of the query being performed in the required script is not available in index.php after the submit. Am i confusing something in terms of load-order/form submit or is this problem specific to some error in my script?

Index.php :

```
session_name("bpsessid");
session_start();



include($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/include/databaseconnect.php");

$oc = mysql_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpassword);
mysql_select_db($dbname);       

    if(isset($auftragsnummer1)) {
    $auftragsnummer1 = strtoupper($auftragsnummer1); 
    }

    require("sql.php");
```

sql.php :

```
    $sqlstring_2 = "SELECT DISTINCT [Ship-to Name] FROM [xxx] WHERE [Related to Sales Order No_]='".mysql_real_escape_string($auftragsnummer1)."' OR [No_]='".mysql_real_escape_string($auftragsnummer1)."' AND [No_] LIKE 'TI%'";
    $result_2 = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sqlstring_2);
    while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result_2, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
      $firma = $row['Ship-to Name'];
      echo $firma;
    }


    $sqlstring_3 = "SELECT DISTINCT [Ship-to Address] FROM [xxx] WHERE [Related to Sales Order No_]='".mysql_real_escape_string($auftragsnummer1)."' OR [No_]='".mysql_real_escape_string($auftragsnummer1)."' AND [No_] LIKE 'TI%'";
    $result_3 = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sqlstring_3, array(), array("Scrollable"=>"buffered"));
    while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result_3, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
      $strasse = $row['Ship-to Address'];
      echo $strasse;
    }

    $sqlstring_4 = "SELECT DISTINCT [Ship-to Post Code] FROM [xxx] WHERE [Related to Sales Order No_]='".mysql_real_escape_string($auftragsnummer1)."' OR [No_]='".mysql_real_escape_string($auftragsnummer1)."' AND [No_] LIKE 'TI%'";
    $result_4 = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sqlstring_4, array(), array("Scrollable"=>"buffered"));
    while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result_4, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
      $plz = $row['Ship-to Post Code'];
      echo $plz;
    }
```

Comment: please post what have you tried till now?

Comment: If i echo the query result in the required script it is output in index.php but if i echo it in index.php there is no output.

Comment: Can you show us the code?

Comment: i added code in the question

Comment: "This is not always the case" so sometimes the data is visible and sometimes not?

Comment: Yes in some cases it worked the first time, most of the time it works when i try a second time. I just copied the sql queries into the index.php script and it always worked. Then i reverted everything to the way it was before and now it always works the first time without changing anything. Magic?

Comment: `$auftragsnummer1` is used  without checking it's existence, maybe moving the `require()` inside that `if(isset())` would unfold the magic.

Comment: Sorry i forgot to include that. The queries mentioned are already in a code block thats checking if auftragnummer1 exists, and i can't just move it in the require because there are other queries that work independently without auftragsnummer1.